# switch for a TabBarView without StoryBoard

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a ConnectionViewController and when i click on the Test button, i would like to switch for a tabViewController.

In my ConnectionViewController :

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender {

    TabBarViewController *tabBarViewController = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];

    [self presentViewController:tabBarViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

but when i click on my test button, the TabBarView is black, without anything.

What could i do to fix that ? I would like a modal segue, not a push.

Thx a lot

**[EDIT] : The solution is to create a custom segue with a class like CustomSegue.m with this method :**

```
-(void) perform {

    ConnectionViewController *src = (ConnectionViewController*) self.sourceViewController;
    TabBarViewController *dest = (TabBarViewController*) self.destinationViewController;

    [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{

        [src presentViewController:dest animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
                    completion:NULL];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the tab bar controller is black is that it does not have any viewControllers to present. You need to set tabBarController.viewControllers property before you present it. Lets say you want to present a tabBarViewController with viewController1 on the first tab and viewController2 on the second tab.

```
tabBarViewController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
```

Comment: Thx ! but now i get this error :  

   ` 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier contestTableCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' `  

While when i segue a other test button with the storyboard from my ConnectionView to TabBarView, there is no problem :/